# How to persist large data for efficient deserialization in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm facing the general problem to compile large data sets to an on-disk representation, which can be efficiently de-serialized to native in-memory Haskell data structures.

More specifically, I have a large amount of graph-data with various attributes associated with edges and vertices. In C/C++ I have compiled the data to a `mmap()`able represenation for maximum efficiency, which currently results in about 200MiB worth of C-structures (and whose text representation is about 600 MiB).

What is the next-best thing I can do in (GHC) Haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the package [binary](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary). It provides a toolbox to efficiently serialize and deserialize data in Haskell. *binary* can automagically derive instances of the requred typeclasses for you, but you can also write optimized instances manually.

Quoted from the originial description page:

> #### The binary package
>
> Efficient, pure binary serialisation
> using lazy ByteStrings. Haskell values
> may be encoded to and from binary
> formats, written to disk as binary, or
> sent over the network. Serialisation
> speeds of over 1 G/sec have been
> observed, so this library should be
> suitable for high performance
> scenarios.

Comment: Do you happen to have a proper link to the source for deriveM? The one in binary's documentation is broken, so theres no way to automatically derive instances.

Comment: On second thought, I found it at http://darcs.haskell.org/libraries/binary/tools/derive/BinaryDerive.hs